# Why this indexed signature is failing?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get an object's values and make them as keys for the interface. Here's what I do:

```
const obj = {
    a: 'foo',
    b: 'bar',
} as const;

type A<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
    [x: string]: T[K];
}[number];

// this one fails with:
// Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'symbol'
type B<T extends object> = {
    [K in A<T>]: any;
};

// even if I do something like this, it still fails with the same error.
type C<T extends typeof obj = typeof obj> = {
    [K in A<T>]: any;
};

// this one works.
type D = {
    [K in A<typeof obj>]: any;
};

// this works, yay.
const a: D = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 1,
};
```

I've never faced anything like this before, can somebody explain why this does not work? (or if there are any better ways to write it)?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that it is not guaranteed that values of passed type are valid to be keys in a new type (`Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'`). This can be fixed with appropriate generic constraint (e.g. `T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>` instead of `T extends object`)

```
type ValuesAsKeys<T extends Record<PropertyKey, PropertyKey>> =
    Record<T[keyof T], any>;

const a: ValuesAsKeys<typeof obj> = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 1,
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAOQBmIIxANNrvEcfHgE7WYC++EMokUA3JkxQAngAcApjABqeADYBXCRACCEANISREADwAVGBIAeUCWAAm3AEoTQzczoAKzEJOajNIqjGeuJ7kU8APiDUWhwbOwc9AG0Aay0QUhg9AF1vPDARIMFMXmh8IllFZTVPXVFJJLgkULQsXBhyECIARhpGpmY2mnZ+IA)

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the values from your object with the following type

```
type Values<T extends object> = T[keyof T]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=10&pln=8&pc=17#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDHMCGAXDAOQBmIIxANNrvEcfHgE7WYC++EMokUA3JkxQAngAcApjABqeADYBXCRAA8AFRgSAHlAlgAJtwSIJwKAD5UMNQG0A1hJEhS1gLpDe0fEQBKpkMz6KrKKyiqiks5wSOZU+GAilmhYuDBMzAx48MBsqeQgRACMNOyYQA)